# How does one use break, continue and return statements to avoid deeply nested code in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style, nested

The [Pocoo style guide](http://www.pocoo.org/internal/styleguide/) advises to use `break`, `continue` and `return` statements to avoid deeply nested code. How would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example would be that instead of this:

```
for item in seq:
    if someCondition:
       # Here is our code block
       if blah:
           more.stuff()
```

you can do this

```
for item in seq:
    if not someCondition:
       continue
   # Now our code block is here
   if blah:
       more.stuff()
```

Note that the latter saves an indentation level.  Obviously you can't always do this, but in some cases it improves readability to handle "if X then stop right away" conditions at the beginning, instead of having to wrap a large stretch of code in an `if` block.

Comment: Both answers are useful but not exhaustive. David gave another case, without for loops.

Comment: @Bentley4: You're unlikely to get an exhaustive answer, because the question is about style.  It's not making any specific claim about any specific piece of code.  It's just saying that in general it's good to follow these kinds of policies.

Comment: I'd say both answers are exhaustive. Both answers illustrate the *concept*. In order to apply this in your code you will need to understand the concept. You won't be able to use the code directly. You'll need to apply the *idea* in your setting.

Comment: Then I suppose I did not ask only after the concept(but perhaps I did not phrase that properly). Without your answer below I would not have thought about that practical solution. But thank you very much for your input though, the answer I accepted for now I deem only barely better, had to choose something. If someone can show multiple practical cases they will get the vote.

Comment: You can only select one. It's your choice which you pick. You made a perfectly good choice. I don't think you need another answer.

Answer (score 2):

For example, instead of writing:

```
if param1Valid:
    if param2Valid:
        ....
```

you can use guard clauses:

```
if not param1Valid:
    return
if not param2Valid:
    return
....
```

Lots of articles extol the virtues of guard clauses:

- http://blog.mafr.de/2009/06/12/a-case-for-guard-clauses/
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html
- http://sourcemaking.com/implementation-patterns/guard-clause

You can use the exact same approach inside a loop with the continue keyword.